# no mapping between account and security windows service

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, windows-services

During the setup of windows service I get the error:

error 1001 no mapping between account and security windows service
We use a custom user account for the server. (administrator account)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid asking the same question again I'm posting my own findings below.

This page mentions something about file Gpttmpl.inf and some possible causes for the mapping error:

> - An account does not exist on domain member computers.
> - A SAM account name differs from its domain account name.
> - The client is running a Multilingual User Interface Pack (MUI) that uses a different default language than the domain controller.
> - A SAM account name was renamed on the client computers.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890737

I am getting similar error when the install on my Windows 7 PC is about to finish.

> Error 1001: No mapping between account names and and security IDs was done

The MSI is generated from a VS 2010 setup project for a .NET Windows service targeting .NET Framework 4.

My MSI would install fine and the service would start fine when using VS 2008. Only after converting service solution to VS 2010 I started getting the issue, even though the domain account  `/USERNAME=thisdomain\thisaccount /PASSWORD=thispasswd` exists and all the requirements above are taken care of.

I did overcome the issue temporarily by removing the original `/USERNAME= /PASSWORD=` values (meant for the server), from the `CustomActionData` property (right-click the setup project, select view, select Custom Actions, right-click the Install Primary output, select properties).

Rebuild the setup project and now the MSI ran/installed the service successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you may not be fully qualifying the account name that you are using for your service.  While this [link](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content.aspx?p=SQL%20Backup&c=knowledgebase%5CSQL_Backup%5CKB200708000131.htm) may be slightly off topic I think it should be helpful.